# How to automatically switch ssh config based on local subnet?

Tags: ssh, ssh-config

I need to jump through an intermediate host to reach my destination when I'm on a certain network (subnet is 10.10.11.x) because of a destination port I can't change and limited ports on which I can exit the restricted network. I use a SSH config like the following with success:

```bash
Host web-direct web
    HostName web.example.com
    Port 1111

Host web-via-jump jweb
    HostName web.example.com
    Port 1111
    ForwardAgent yes
    ProxyCommand ssh -p 110 -q relay.example.com nc %h %p
```

Going through the jumpbox is a significant performance hit, so I need to avoid it for the majority of times that it is not needed. Switching the `ssh`/`scp`/`rsync` host nickname is fine for interactive use, but there are some automated/scripted tasks which it is very painful.

My shell stays open across network transitions, so startup (*.zshrc*) mechanisms don't help.

I've thought of running a script to poll for the restricted subnet and automating the switch by modifying the *.ssh/config* file, but I'm not even sure there would be a caching issue. Before I implement that, I thought I would ask if there is a better approach.

What's the best approach for swapping out SSH config based on origin host subnet detection?

In pseudo-config, something like:

```bash
if <any-active-local-interface> is on 10.10.11.x:
    Host web
        HostName web.example.com
        Port 1111
        ForwardAgent yes
        ProxyCommand ssh -p 110 -q relay.example.com nc %h %p
else:    
    Host web
        HostName web.example.com
        Port 1111
endif
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40747099/241211) by Fedor Dikarev, [Mike created](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40746463/2) a bash script named `onsubnet`:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [[ "$1" == "--help" ]] || [[ "$1" == "-h" ]]  || [[ "$1" == "" ]] ; then
  printf "Usage:\n\tonsubnet [ --not ] partial-ip-address\n\n"
  printf "Example:\n\tonsubnet 10.10.\n\tonsubnet --not 192.168.0.\n\n"
  printf "Note:\n\tThe partial-ip-address must match starting at the first\n"
  printf "\tcharacter of the ip-address, therefore the first example\n"
  printf "\tabove will match 10.10.10.1 but not 110.10.10.1\n"
  exit 0
fi

on=0
off=1
if [[ "$1" == "--not" ]] ; then
  shift
  on=1
  off=0
fi

regexp="^$(sed 's/\./\\./g' <<<"$1")"

if [[ "$(uname)" == "Darwin" ]] ; then
  ifconfig | grep -F 'inet ' | grep -Fv 127.0.0. | cut -d ' ' -f 2 | grep -Eq "$regexp"
else
  hostname -I | tr -s " " "\012" | grep -Fv 127.0.0. | grep -Eq "$regexp"
fi

if [[ $? == 0 ]]; then 
  exit $on
else
  exit $off
fi
```

Then in his `.ssh/config` file, he uses `Match exec` like [Jakuje's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40747254/241211):

```bash
Match exec "onsubnet 10.10.1." host my-server
    HostName web.example.com
    Port 1111
    ForwardAgent yes
    ProxyCommand ssh -p 110 -q relay.example.com nc %h %p

Match exec "onsubnet --not 10.10.1." host my-server
    HostName web.example.com
    Port 1111
```

Answer (score 27):

You can use [`Match`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config.5#Match)'s `exec` option to execute shell commands, so you can write something like this:

```sh
Match host web exec "hostname -I | grep -qF 10.10.11."
    ForwardAgent yes
    ProxyCommand ssh -p 110 -q relay.example.com nc %h %p
Host web
    HostName web.example.com
    Port 1111
```

The `Match` option boolean logic can short-circuit, so put `host` first to skip the `exec` term for other hosts. Try `ssh web -vvv` to see the `Match` logic in action.

Comment: Instead of comparing the local IP address I used `Match host ... exec "ip route | grep ^192.168.123.0/24"` to check if there is access to the target network

Comment: I went with `Match Host * exec "resolvectl query %h 2>&1 | grep 10.20.0."` - this matches when I pass a 10.20.0.x IP address or when I pass a hostname which resolves to 10.20.0.x

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to match an IP is the use of a regex like this:

```sh
Match exec "[[ '%h' =~ ^10\.10\.11\. ]]"
   ...
```

You can expand it to match additional IPs:

```sh
Match exec "[[ '%h' =~ ^10\.10\.1(1|2)\. ]]"
   ...
```

Comment: I see in the ssh config docs that `%h    The remote hostname`in the TOKENS section but the IP match is for the local IP address. How would this work? Is this a different %h?

Comment: Hello Mike, Right %h is the remote host. Between the double quotes is shell syntax. In this case a regular expression matching. If i run ˋssh 10.10.11.3ˋ it matches and all directives behind like a proxycommand will be asigned. Any futher questions? Best Olli

Answer (score 4):

OpenSSH 9.4 added [a new match predicate `match localnetwork`](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-9.4) that can match a list of CIDR-format addresses. So to matching if the client is on the subnet `10.10.12.0/24` while defaulting to use a VPN IP address otherwise can be done with:

```
Match Host pi localnetwork 10.10.12.0/24
    HostName 10.10.12.4

Host pi
    HostName 10.0.0.2
    User turtvaiz
    Identityfile ~/.ssh/id_pi
```

You can also match multiple subnets with a list, e.g. `localnetwork 10.10.12.0/24,10.0.0.0/24`.

Comment: Thanks. However, it does not seem to be supported on OpenSSH_for_Windows_9.4p1, "match localnetwork: not supported on this platform", see source code https://github.com/PowerShell/openssh-portable/blob/cb23f0d9c0f4d40edbc2863419dcff40ebd5e0a6/readconf.c#L647

Comment: I didn't notice that you had added this in between my visits to this question, and accidentally added a duplicate answer (now deleted).

Answer (score 2):

My solution to this problem is the following:

```sh
Host myserver
    HostName [internal IP]
    ...
    
Match Host [internal IP] !Exec "nc -w1 -q0 %h %p < /dev/null"
    ProxyCommand ssh jumphost -W %h:%p
```

It's important to have the `Host myserver` lines first, so the SSH client will know the IP address.

In the `Match` expression,

- The `Host` option matches on that IP. (It accepts `*`, so you can match to /8, /16 or /24 subnets too.)
- The `Exec` option executes a `netcat` with a 1 second timeout to test if the SSH port is open. If not, the `ProxyCommand` is used.

This is the clearest way I found to actually test if you need a jumphost or not. If your network is lagging, you can set higher timeouts, of course. See [`man ssh_config`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/ssh_config.5.html) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the following function for that:

```sh
function ssh() {
  network=`networksetup -getairportnetwork en0 | cut -d: -f2 | tr -d [:space:]`
  if [ -n "$network" -a -f $HOME/.ssh/config.$network ]; then
    /usr/bin/ssh -F $HOME/.ssh/config.$network "$@"
  else
    /usr/bin/ssh "$@"
  fi
}
export -f ssh
```

So I need a separate configuration file for each WiFi network where I want a custom solution. It works for me right now, but it's ugly. I can recommend it only as an idea, not as the best solution.

I'd be glad to know any better solution.

Comment: I'm guessing this doesn't address rsync, scp and/or git. Have you tried those?

Comment: It's only alias, it doesn't impact other programs. For `scp` and `rsync` it's easy to make similar aliases and for `git` not sure it will be easy. @Jakuje give solution using `Match exec`, I will rewrite my configuration as it looks like better solution.

Comment: If you get the `Match exec` solution working please comment with your experience. I would change grep to fgrep unless you want to use a real regexp.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of [checking the subnet CIDR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40747254/241211), you can check what domain suffix DHCP has given you.

- If you're trying to use a jump box when outside the intranet, this approach is more robust than checking for IP ranges in the [reserved private](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918) allocation (e.g. your home network or remote-work location uses the same block as `example.com`'s intranet).
- This approach is *not* useful if your intranet uses the same DNS suffix everywhere and you're trying to traverse subnets within the intranet. If that's your situation, use [Jakuje's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40747254/241211).

```sh
Match Host web Exec "hostname -d | ! grep -q -E '^example\.com'"
    ForwardAgent yes
    ProxyCommand ssh -p 110 -q relay.example.com nc %h %p
Host web
    HostName web.example.com
    Port 1111
```

If you don't have a recent version of `hostname` that has the `-d` option (e.g. you're on MacOS), you can just query `resolve.conf` directly:

```sh
Match Host web Exec "! grep -q -E '^\s*search[ \t]+example\.com' /etc/resolv.conf"
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: An alternative to the `hostname` command on macOS is the `scutil` tool. E.g. `scutil --dns | grep -qE '^\s+search domain...\s+:\s+example.com'` (this looks for the search domain setting, which may or may not be helpful depending on your particular network config).