# GPG key forwarding on Debian

Tags: ssh, debian, smartcard, gnupg, openpgp

I'm trying to use the private key from my openpgp card from my Debian laptop to a RPi. I followed the different hints found on google, in particular:

- extra-socket in `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`
- removed it again when founding that this extra socket already will be created in `/run/user/<uid>/gnupg`
- forward this socket using `~/.ssh/config`

`Host homegear
HostName homegear
RemoteForward ~/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent /run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.extra`

- changed the order of the both sockets in the RemoteForward line since I'm always confused which one should be the first one
- add the following into `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` of the RPi

`StreamLocalBindUnlink yes`

- reload the gpg-agent on the laptop
- open new ssh connection to RPi

But I always get

```
Warning: remote port forwarding failed for listen path ~/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent
```

when connecting to the RPi.

`openssh` on both laptop and RPi is 7.4 (Debian Stretch), `gpg` is 2.1.18.
Forwarding the agent connect to be used as ssh private key (for connecting to gitlab from RPi) works perfectly, forwarding gpg private key (for signing commits) doesn't. I'm a bit helpless at the moment. Is there anything obviously wrong? Or is there still a problem with forwarding unix domain socket and I need to use the socat workaround?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've run into exactly the same issue except between two Macs running 10.14.2 and GPG 2.2.11, and the only way I was able to get it to work was to specify the absolute path to the sockets on *both* ends. :( Having a relative path for either the remote or local socket both failed in various ways, which makes it a bit of a pain if you're connecting as different usernames on various machines.

I was able to work around that by specifying a number of different `Match exec` blocks in my `~/.ssh/config`:

```
# Source machine is a personal Mac, connecting to another personal Mac on my local network
Match exec "hostname | grep -F .core" Host *.core
    RemoteForward /Users/virtualwolf/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent /Users/virtualwolf/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent.extra

# Source machine is a personal Mac, connecting to my Linux box
Match exec "hostname | grep -F .core" Host <name of the host block for my Linux box>
    RemoteForward /home/virtualwolf/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent /Users/virtualwolf/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent.extra

# Source machine is my work Mac, connecting to my Linux box
Match exec "hostname | grep -F <work machine name>" Host <name of the host block for my Linux box>
    RemoteForward /home/virtualwolf/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent /Users/<work username>/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent.extra
```

(SSH bits are taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40747254/677767)).